# How do you clear an immutable.js map back to its defaults

Tags: redux, immutable.js

I have an immutable.js map. For example:

// default, when user first gets on page

```
var myObject = Immutable.Map({
  productID: '',
  colors: ['brown', 'red'],
  sku: ''
  sizes: [10]
})
```

Now, depending on how they get to my app - I populate that above "myObject" with different data.

so, for example: lets say they come from pathA
// pathA passes in some data... hydrate the myObject

```
var myObject = Immutable.Map({
  productID: '090ABl',
  colors: ['brown', 'red', 'yellow'],
  sku: '__whatever'
  sizes: [10, 18, 9]
})
```

so, for example: lets say they come from pathB

** this is where the issue comes from. I have that previous "state" of myObject hanging around. I need to "clear and go back to the initial state". I am using redux.

// pathB passes in some data... hydrate the myObject

```
var myObject = Immutable.Map({
  productID: '090XZLG',
  colors: ['red', 'yellow'],
  sku: '__food'
  sizes: [9]
})
```

The data is combing etc.. I need it to "clear out.". Curious if there is an Immutable.js method that enables to refresh the myObject with a new one, that is the same as the initial state. I am new to immutable.js so I am a bit curious about why its so hard to do simple things :-)

Comment: Just keep a reference to your initial/default state object, e.g. named `defaultObject`, then once the user visits the page, you populate that.

Answer (score 1):

When using immutable for the state object in redux, in many of my reducers I `set` a certain key to what I `get` from the initial state.
i.e.:

```
function reeducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case CLEAR_SELECTION:
      return state.set('selected', initialState.get('selected'));
    ...
  }
}
```

And of course to make it a bit cleaner (specially to avoid repeating a string) one could create a function for this:

```
function resetKey(state, initialState, key) {
    return state.set(key, initialState.get(key));
}
```

(Alternatively it could be called copyKey or copySection)
Or it could be a resetPath/copyPath

```
function resetPath(state, initialState, path) {
    return state.setIn(key, initialState.getIn(path));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The immutable.js object does not 'know' what its 'defaults' are, so there is no way of resetting it. If you have a default object in your application just keep a reference to that in a variable, like you would if it were a plain JavaScript object:

```
var defaultObject = Immutable.Map({
  productID: '',
  colors: ['brown', 'red'],
  sku: ''
  sizes: [10]
})
```

Then when the user arrives at a certain path, you simply make your modifications and keep them in a different variable:

```
var myObject = defaultObject.set(...);
```